# SQL: only show entry if there is no other entry with special different value in same table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, distinct

```
ID    ID_A   Status  
175   473    2    
174   473    1    
173   455    2
170   412    2
169   397    1
168   393    2
173   391    2
```

Thats my example table. As result I want it to display only entries with Status=1, Grouped by ID_A. It must not contain the results with Status=2!
Result should look like this:

```
ID_A   Status
397    1
```

My problem is that there can be two similar ID_A entries. Dont know if thats easy doable with COUNT or DISTINCT? Im somehow not gettint it at the moment.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT x.id_a x.status FROM a x LEFT JOIN a y ON y.id_a = x.id_a AND y.status = 2 WHERE x.status = 1 AND y.id_a IS NULL;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sometimes called an *exclusion join*.

You do an outer join to try to find the row that would invalidate your condition. Where there is no such row, the outer join will put NULL into all the columns of the joined table, and then you have a match.

```
SELECT t1.ID_A, t1.Status
FROM exampletable AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN exampletable AS t2
    ON t1.ID_A = t2.ID_A AND t2.Status = 2 
WHERE t1.Status = 1
    AND t2.ID IS NULL;
```

---

Re comment from @Strawberry:

A US patent from 2001, ["Optimizing an exclusion join operation using a bitmap index structure"](https://www.google.com/patents/US6957210) defines an exclusion join:

> An exclusion join operation selects rows in a first table having values in specified columns where the values cannot be found in a specified column of a second table. A database system may execute such a query by excluding entries in the first table that match entries in the second table.

That patent also cites a paper from 1993, ["Parallel implementations of exclusion joins"](http://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings/spdp/1993/4222/00/0395458-abs.html)

I assume the term also predates that paper.

Comment: I call it an exclusion join too, but I don't if I've ever seen that written down anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select id_a, group_concat(status) as statuses
from table t
group by id_a
having sum(status = 2) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select t.id_A,t.status
from exampletabla as t
where t.status = 1 and t.id_A not in (select id_A from exampletabla where status = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct x.id_a, x.status
  from tbl x
 where status = 1
   and not exists (select 'y'
          from tbl y
         where x.id_a = y.id_a
           and status = 2)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I didn't put any links in this post, did you mean to comment on something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can approach as finding first the unique entries from the column and then finding the exact value by your condition.

```
select ID_A ,Status 
FROM testTbl 
group by ID_A 
having COUNT(*) = 1 and Status  = 1;
```

Hope it helps.